# Link images on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, containers, dockerhub

I want push my app in a docker image on docker hub, but my app needs a database.
How do I automatic link my app with a database image (postgres) in docker hub?

Obs: Docker hub doesn't support docker compose.

Comment: I would expose the port and give instructions on usage about how to link with the appropriate docker. Case in point: https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/ . They don't include mysql server in the image, but give instructions how to include using docker-compose and docker run.

Comment: That's right. The Hub isn't for applications or services, it's to host images as they are. Any information on how and why an image could be used goes in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, this isn't really the purpose of Docker Hub. Docker Hub stores and provides publicly accessible container images that developers can use to build complete applications from, using tools like Docker Compose.

However, with that in mind, you'll want to keep an eye on the new Docker Store, which is currently promising to provide full-featured applications running in Docker containers.

Here's a blog post that talks about it: https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-store/